# How to get item titles from custom post type in php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

so I have created custom post types in WordPress called podcasts with different packages and most of it has been completed now what I'm trying to do is to "get each available podcast / item title underneath the package" for example I've 3 packages called Basic, Starter and Exclusive and I want to display all items available in Basic package underneath the Basic Bundle and same for Starter and Exclusive. I have mentioned the code below currently it's showing all the item titles.

```
<div class="container-intro-head">
<div class="row">
                        
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="package-head-intro">BASIC BUNDLE - $9.99</h3>
        <?php if($get_packages_list){?>
        
        <?php foreach($get_packages_list as $get_package){
            $podcasts = get_field('podcasts', $get_package->ID);
            $minimum_price = get_field('minimum_price', $get_package->ID);
            foreach($podcasts as $podcast){
            $podcast_details = get_post($podcast);
            ?>              
                                            
            <!--Display Items only available in Basic Bundle-->
            <h5 class="item-main-title"><?php echo $podcast_details->post_title; ?></h5>
                                            
            <?php 
            }
            }?>             
            <?php }?>
    </div>
                            
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="package-head-intro">STARTER BUNDLE - $14.99</h3>
    </div>
                            
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="package-head-intro">EXCLUSIVE BUNDLE - $19.99</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its like regular posts, use `get_the_title($post->ID)`

Comment: @Breezer, I did it already and the titles are displaying but what I'm trying to do here is "<h5 class="item-main-title"><?php echo $podcast_details->post_title; ?></h5>"

Comment: and what you can do is <?php the_title($podcast_details->ID); ?> OR  <?php echo get_the_title($podcast_details->ID); ?>

Comment: or I might be misunderstanding your question entirely, you could always `print_r` your `$podvast_details` to see what you have and what you can print

Comment: @Breezer, I did it already and I'm getting the titles but what I'm trying to do it display the titles separately for all three packages means what should I write in below code to get the items only for Basic Package? 
<h5 class="item-main-title"><?php echo $podcast_details->post_title; ?></h5>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for

```
<div class="container-intro-head">
<div class="row">
                        
    
        <?php if($get_packages_list){?>
        
        <?php foreach($get_packages_list as $get_package){
  $podcasts = get_field('podcasts', $get_package->ID);
            $minimum_price = get_field('minimum_price', $get_package->ID);
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="package-head-intro"><?=get_the_title($get_package->ID);?></h3>
<?php
          
            foreach($podcasts as $podcast){
            $podcast_details = get_post($podcast);
            ?>              
                                            
            <!--Display Items only available in Basic Bundle-->
            <h5 class="item-main-title"><?php echo $podcast_details->post_title; ?></h5>
                                            
            <?php 
            }
?>
    </div>
<?php
            }?>             
            <?php }?>

                            
   
</div>
```

you get to solve the details i guess :)